# Git diff all local changes, regardless which commit or staged/unstaged

Tags: git

One of the things I dislike about Git is the diff command changes depending whether it's unstaged, staged, committed etc.

I have a branch and I have only `git push`ed for review. Nothing has been pushed to the master branch. However, I would like to make one final check of every line I have changed, even if it's currently not staged.

I have this command:

`git difftool @{upstream}`

but it seems to only show the difference since the last commit.

How can I just compare everything (staged, un-staged, staged during previous commit) with the master branch?

Comment: The command you show should compare your worktree state to whatever `@{upstream}` resolves. It should be everything, staged or unstaged. If that is not what you want, you should illustrate your branch and what you want to compare to what.

Answer (score 3):

#### TL;DR

Your existing `git diff` or `git difftool` command *probably should* get you everything you would like to know.  If it doesn't ... well, as [j6t commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61614944/git-diff-all-local-changes-regardless-which-commit-or-staged-unstaged#comment108993931_61614944), we can't read your mind.  Maybe another thing you want is `git diff origin/master @{upstream}` or `git difftool origin/master @{upstream}` here.

#### Long

There *is* a problem or two here, but it's kind of hard to describe precisely.  Confusingly, the problem usually isn't a problem either.  To put it as briefly as I can: `git diff` only compares *two things* (well, sort of: the details get a bit sticky, later).  Sometimes we want to compare more than two things, and to do that, we need multiple `git diff` commands.

The trick, then, is to know *what Git is comparing*, i.e., what two things went into the diff.  You really do need to know *all* of this stuff to understand what Git is doing and why, so as to use the tools Git provides in an effective manner.  So what I'll do is describe what `git diff` and `git difftool` actually do.

#### Key background (long)

Remember that Git is all about *commits:*

- Commits have hash IDs, and these are their "true names", as it were.  Git actually finds commits by their hash IDs.
- Each commit has a full and complete snapshot of all of your files.  This snapshot is its main data.  Each commit also has some metadata, such as the name of the person who made it, when they made it (date and time stamp), and why they made it (their log message).  Using `git log` with no additional options, you see just the hash ID and metadata.
- The files inside each commit are completely, totally, 100% read-only.  They're stored in a special Git-only frozen format, compressed and de-duplicated (so that it doesn't matter that every commit stores every file: there's only one copy of each version anyway).
- In fact, everything about a commit—including all of its metadata—is read-only, frozen for all time.  And, in that metadata, each commit lists the hash IDs of its *parent* commits.  Usually there's just one hash ID here.  (Merge commits have at least two, and usually exactly two.  Having more than one is what makes them merge commits.)
- Branch names, tag names, fancy things like `@{upstream}`, and so on are mostly just ways to name specific commits.  Branch names have the special property that you can get "on" them (`git status` says `on branch master`), and when you do that, a *new* commit makes the branch name identify the new commit, instead of identifying the commit you got out with `git checkout`.
- Hence, by definition, a branch name identifies the *last* commit in the branch.  Earlier commits are also contained in that branch, which works by following the parent hash IDs in each commit's metadata.

But if all files inside every commit are only usable by Git, and are impossible to *change*, how can we ever get any work done?  The answer is that `git checkout` *extracts* the files from the archived committed versions.  These files become ordinary everyday files, that we can see and edit and so on.

These ordinary everyday files are stored in what Git calls the *working tree* or *work-tree*.  But they're not actually in the *repository* at all!  This becomes very important pretty quickly.

(We'll get back to "staged" in a moment.)

> I have a branch and I have only `git push`ed for review.

When you use `git push`, you have your Git call up some other Git.  Your Git then sends that other Git any *commits* you have that they don't.  All of this works by hash IDs, because the hash ID of any commit is the same in *every* Git.  The uniqueness of the hash IDs is what enables all of this.  Two Gits can share a commit, and one Git can tell if it has another Git's commit, just by the hash ID.  Your Git says *I offer you, other Git, hash ID ______* (fill in the blank) and they look at this and see if they have it.  If not, they ask for it and your Git offers its *parent* commits and this all goes around again; or if they have it, your Git is done with the offering part.

So that's how your Git knows which commits to send them: the ones they don't have, that you made and are now sending with your `git push`, are the ones that get sent.  Then, at the end, your Git asks their Git to set one of *their* branch names to identify the *last* commit in the chain you just sent.<sup>1</sup>

What this all means is that you can *only* push *commits*.  You cannot push any files from your work-tree, which aren't even in the repository at all.  And when we cover *staging* some file(s) in a moment, you can't push staged files either. You can only push *commits*.

---

<sup>1</sup>Actually, you can ask them to set multiple names in one `git push`.  The only initial requirement here is that to ask them to set some name *N* to hash ID *H*, they have to *have* the object with hash ID *H* by now.  For commits, that means your Git should offer to send them commit *H* first, and then actually send it if they say *yes please*, or not if they say *no thanks, I have that already*.

Once they have the request to set _____ (name) to _____ (hash ID), they can check whether they wish to allow that name to be set that way, or not.  Your push then either succeeds, or gets an error (`! rejected ...`), based on their reply to this request.

---

#### Diffing commits

A commit holds a snapshot—a full copy of all of your files.

Most of the time, we don't want to look at the *snapshot as a whole* though.  That's way too much stuff.  If we do want to look at the snapshot as a whole, we use `git checkout` to extract its files into our work-tree, and then we can use all our file-browsing / editing tools on those.  That commit becomes the *current commit*.  Git always knows which commit you have as the *current* one—the last one you `git checkout`-ed (or `git switch`-ed to, in Git 2.23 and later).

What we'd like, though, is to *compare* one snapshot to another.

The `git diff` and `git difftool` commands can do this:

```
git diff <left-side-commit> <right-side-commit>
```

(or the same with `git difftool`).  What this does is:

- extract all of the left-side commit to a temporary area
- extract all of the right-side commit to a temporary area
- match up the left and right side files:

  - for each file that is *the same*, do nothing
  - for each file that is *different*, show the difference (`git diff`) or run another command to show the difference (`git difftool`)

When Git itself shows the difference, it uses its own built in variant of [XDiff](http://www.xmailserver.org/xdiff-lib.html) to compute a recipe: *make these changes to the left-side file, and you'll get the right-side file.*  This is very line-oriented: even if you use the word-diff functions, Git starts out by finding the changed *lines*, and then post-processes the result to get changed words.

The recipe that comes out of `git diff` is not necessarily what whoever edited the files actually *did*.  It's just a recipe that produces the same *result*.  Of course, if you use `git difftool`, it's up to some other program—your chosen tool—to show you what happened, in whatever way that tool does that job.

#### Commits only exist once they're *committed*

While `git diff` can tell you *this is how to change commit X into commit Y*, we have a work-tree where we have ordinary files, and maybe we have changed those ordinary files.  It sure would be nice if Git could tell us what we've changed here.

Git *can*.  Instead of putting one commit on the left and another commit on the right, Git can put a commit on the left, and use our work-tree full of files *as if* it were the right-side commit.  So that's what:

```
git diff <left-side-commit>
```

does: we name the left side commit, however we like—by hash ID, or by name such as `master` or `branch` or `@{upstream}`—and Git extracts that commit to a temporary area, then compares that commit to the work-tree files.

#### What about staged files?

This is where things get interesting, and a little odd.  Git doesn't just have *committed* files—files saved forever inside commits, in a read-only, Git-only, compressed and frozen format—and ordinary files in our work-tree that aren't in the repository at all.  Git also has a *third* copy of each file,<sup>2</sup> saved in an area that Git has three names for.

This area is called, variously, the *index*, or the *staging area*, or—rarely these days—the *cache*, depending on who / what part of Git is doing the calling.  The index—I'll use that name here, mostly—has multiple purposes, but its main big one, and the way to think about it, is this: the index holds the *proposed next commit*.

What's in the index, in other words, is a copy of every file, ready to go into the next commit.  These copies are in the frozen *format*, but since they are not in a commit yet, they're not actually *frozen*.  You can replace them wholesale.  You can also remove them entirely—which means the removed file *won't* be in the next commit at all—or add all-new files, which means the next commit will have a file that isn't in this current commit.

The index starts out matching the current commit.  That is, every file that's in the commit is now in the index too, and files that aren't in the commit, are not in the index.

Running `git add path` takes the named file and copies it into the index.  Whatever copy was there before is now replaced.  If there wasn't a copy before, now there is.  Either way, people call this *staging the file for commit*.  But there was a file there before, usually.  We've just *replaced* it.

When you run `git status`, Git does *two* `git diff` operations.  Both are run with a flag that says *don't find a change recipe, just find out if there are changes*.<sup>3</sup>

The first `git diff` compares the *current commit* to the index.  Wherever files are the same here, Git says nothing.  For files that are different, Git says *staged for commit*.

The second `git diff` compares the index to your work-tree.  Wherever files are the same here, Git says nothing.  For files that are different, Git says *not staged for commit*.

When you do get around to running `git commit`, Git packages up all the files that are in the index—they are already in the frozen format, which makes this easy—and writes out a new commit.  The new commit's parent is the current commit.  The new commit gets a new, unique hash ID.  Except for the parent (current commit) and time-stamps ("now"), the metadata comes from stuff you provide: your name and email address and a log message.  And now the new commit, with its new hash ID, is frozen for all time, and if `git status` says `on branch xyz`, Git stuffs the new commit's hash ID into your branch-name `xyz`.

---

<sup>2</sup>Technically, what's in Git's index isn't a *copy* of the file, but rather information *about* a copy of the file.  The copied content of the file is saved as an internal Git *blob object*.  You don't need to know or care about this unless you make a deep dive into Git and use `git ls-files --stage`, or `git update-index`.  You can just think about the index copy of a file as "a copy", and it all just works.

<sup>3</sup>You can use this flag yourself: `git diff --name-status`.  The output format is a bit different: `git status` tries to present the results in a more user-friendly fashion.

---

#### The four main ways to run `git diff` or `git difftool`

To make the staging area itself play a part in `git diff` or `git difftool`, you may need the option `--cached` or `--staged`.  Both mean exactly the same thing.

- `git diff` without extra names: If we want to compare the staging area vs the work-tree, the command for this is `git diff`, with *no additional names or commit hashes*.  (Flags, such as `--name-status`, are still allowed of course.)  Git puts the index on the left and the work-tree on the right, and compares the two.
- `git diff commit1 commit2`: If we want to compare two commits to each other, this does that job.  Git puts the first commit (by name or hash ID) on the left, and the second on the right.
- `git diff commit`: Compares a commit to the current work-tree.  Git puts the named commit on the left and the work-tree on the right.
- `git diff --cached commit`: Compares a commit to the index / staging-area.  The named commit goes on the left and the index's files are on the right.
- `git diff --cached`: Compares the current commit to the index / staging-area, as if we ran `git diff --cached HEAD`.  (This is a fifth way if you count bullet points, but it's really exactly the same as the fourth way.)

All of the above applies to `git difftool` as well: as before, it puts one thing on the left and the other thing on the right.  Instead of having Git itself come up with a change-recipe, though, it invokes your preferred tool to compare each different file.  As always, it just skips right over identical files.

#### A few special cases

The `git diff` command can do a few more things, such as compare two specified files.  It also has a special mode that it uses in exactly two cases, one of which is normally invoked via `git show`.

The `git show` command is pretty handy.  It's like `git log` but with patch mode turned on, for one commit:<sup>4</sup>

```
git show <commit>
```

shows you the log message and then a diff.  The diff compares the commit's *parent* to the commit.  Since the parent holds the "before" snapshot, and the commit itself holds the "after" snapshot, the result is a recipe: *do this to the before-commit's content, and you'll get the named commit's content.*

When you use `git show` on a *merge* commit, however, there isn't just one parent.  This invokes `git diff` in a special way, where `git diff` runs more than one diff.  Git diffs *each* parent against the child commit, one at a time.  Then it *combines* these diffs into what it calls a *combined diff*.

Combined diffs are a bit disappointing, at least to me, because the rules here *throw out* any file that matches from *any* parent to the child.  That is, if you took a file unchanged from one side of a merge, throwing away all the work someone did on the other branch, `git show` *doesn't show you that*.  Sometimes that was the mistake that you're looking for, and `git show` just doesn't show it.  You can force `git show` to break this up into multiple separate `git diff`s—use `git show -m`—and that's often the way to find this problem, when it's the problem.

A simple `git diff`, to compare the index to the work-tree, will also use the combined-diff code if you are in the middle of a conflicted merge.  The details are a bit complicated and I won't cover them here.  You literally *can't* commit when you are in this conflicted merge mode, though, so this never applies to code review cases.

---

<sup>4</sup>`git show` can do a lot more things too.  Read [its documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show) for details.

---

#### Conclusion

As long as you're interested in what happened in *commits*, the way to find out is to use the two-commit form:

```
git diff <commit-1> <commit-2>
```

or use `git show` to automatically compare parent vs child:

```
git show <commit>
```

You *can* use the `git diff commit` form, which compares the given commit to the work-tree, *if* the work-tree content matches the desired *`commit-2`* content.  But if you want to compare two commits, you need *two* names, or *two* hash IDs, or a mix of one each, for instance.

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate your extensive reply. You won't like my comment, but I strongly dislike Git so I apologise, this isn't aimed towards you (unless you designed Git). However, surely I should be able to check all my work without any commit ID? Surely it's a reasonable ask to just know what have I changed, regardless of commits? Because otherwise (and this is the stage I'm at) I don't want to commit separately because as soon as I do, it's a nightmare to diff.

Comment: I definitely didn't design Git. From a user experience point of view it's a nightmare (vs Mercurial, which is pretty pleasant to beginners). Git really forces you to know all this stuff. In any case, as j6t and I said, your existing command *should* be working, unless you've hit any one of the complications I've outlined here. If it's not working for you, you're probably in one of these complicated situations.

Comment: Okay so this is the command which seems to work: git diff my_branch..master

Comment: @user997112: yes: `git diff my_branch..master` means the same thing as `git diff my_branch master`—`git diff` essentially replaces the two dots this way—and that in turn means *compare the commit selected by the name `my_branch` with the commit selected by the name `master`*. That is, you're doing `git diff <commit-1> <commit-2>`. You can name commits by any of the methods shown in [the gitrevisions documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions).

Comment: Note that when you do `git checkout master` or `git checkout my_branch`, you're still specifying a *commit*. However, `git checkout` does something special with branch names: it checks out that commit (as found by the name), but *also* puts you "on the branch". This means *new* commits you make will add to the branch, changing the hash ID selected *by* the *name*.

Comment: When you do a `git checkout` (or in GIt 2.23 or later, `git switch`—the old `checkout` command has too many jobs so the Git folks finally, after years of prodding, broke it out into two separate commands), Git fills its index, and your work-tree, from the commit you select. If you use a *branch name* to select the commit, it puts you "on the branch". If you use a raw hash ID, or a name that isn't a branch name, it leaves you in "detached HEAD" mode. This UI / UX is ... not friendly. (It is pretty efficient though, once you've spent months learning all this stuff.)